# How to store the hit count of a page in a sharepoint list.

Tags: list, javascript, jquery

I have created a page and now I want to get the track of hit count of that page. I want to store that no. in a sharepoint list.

On every page load the count should get increased by 1 and get stored in a sharepoint list.

Please suggest only out of the box approach or javascript or jquery code.

Comment: There are native capabilities of tracking and statistic. What's missing in the native feature ? The stats are basics, but your description seems to fit

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done by creating a custom list with a 1 number column to store the value. Create an element in this list with 0 as value. Then create a script that gets and increments this value through the REST API for lists, and the saves the new value in the list. Add this script in a Script Editor Web Part.

Comment: Thanks Jan for you reply. I am new to sharepoint therefore I am not able to understand how to increase value through the REST API using script. Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    console.log('Enterned');
    retriveListItem();
});

 function retriveListItem()  
{  
    var currentDate=new Date();
    var today=new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(),currentDate.getMonth(),currentDate.getDate());
    var spUrl =_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HitCount')/items?$select=ID,Count,CurrentDate&$filter=CurrentDate eq '"+today.toISOString().substring(0,10)+"'";

    $.ajax  
    ({  

        url: encodeURI(spUrl),
        type: "GET",        
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
        cache: false,  
        success: function(data)   
        {  

           if(data.d.results.length >0)
            {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)   
            {  
                var item = data.d.results[i];  
                updateListItem(item.ID,item.Count +1);

            }
            }
            else{
                 var ListDate =(CurrentDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + CurrentDate.getDate() + '/' + CurrentDate.getFullYear()
                AddListItem(ListDate,1);
            }

        },  
        error: function(data)  
        {  

            console.log('Request failed. ' + data.responseJSON.error);
        }  
    }); 
}

 function AddListItem(DateField,CountInc)  
{ 
var data = {
            __metadata: { 'type': 'SP.Data.HitCountListItem' },
           CurrentDate:DateField,
           Count:CountInc
      };

        $.ajax({
                    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HitCount')/items",
                   method: "POST",
                                 data: JSON.stringify(data),
                   headers: {
                       "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                        "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
                        "X-HTTP-Method": "POST" 

                   },
        success: function(data)  
        {  
            console.log("Record Inserted Sucessfully");
        },  
        error: function(data)  
        {  
        console.log('Request failed. ' + data.responseJSON.error);
        }  
    });  


}

function updateListItem(ID,CountInc)  
{  

    $.ajax  
    ({  
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('HitCount')/items("+ID+")",
         type: "POST",  
        data: JSON.stringify  
        ({  
            __metadata:  
            {  
                type: "SP.Data.HitCountListItem"  
            },  
            Count: CountInc  
        }),  
        headers:  
        {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),  
            "IF-MATCH": "*",  
            "X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"  
        },  
        success: function(data, status, xhr)  
        {  
            //retriveListItem();
              console.log("Updated the Record");

        },  
        error: function(xhr, status, error)  
        {  
            console.log(data.responseJSON.error);  
        }  
    });
}   

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Hit counter for SharePoint for the way "Jan Maximilian W. Kristiansen" explained above
 * ---------------------------------------------
 * Created by Manmohan Tomar
 * List Name: HitCounter with Title, URL, Counter, Time & User columns
 * This will create a new list item each time for different pages/urls
 * If new items are not required then update the list not add item each time
*/


/* Call this below function hitCounter() in doc ready */

function hitCounter(){

var LoggedInName;
var URLLink = window.location.href.toLowerCase();

getLoggedInUser().done(function(LoggedInNameTemp){
      LoggedInName = LoggedInNameTemp;



checkCounterVal(function(retCntrVal) {  

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('HitCounter');       

    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo); 
    oListItem.set_item('Title', "PageVisited");
    oListItem.set_item('URL', URLLink);
    oListItem.set_item('Counter', retCntrVal+1);
    oListItem.set_item('Time', new Date($.now()));
    oListItem.set_item('User', LoggedInName); 

    oListItem.update();
    clientContext.load(oListItem,'Include(Title, URL, Counter, Time, User)');

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onQueryFailed));



}); //checkCounterVal closed



}).fail(function(error){
      alert(error.get_message());
    });  //getLoggedInUser closed



}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

alert("Page visit value increased by 1");

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed to save page visit counter: ' + args.get_message() + ' \n and \n ' + args.get_stackTrace());

}


function getLoggedInUser(listTitle,propertiesToInclude)
{ 
   var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();    
    clientContext.load(currentUser);
    //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,onRetUsrQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this,onRetUsrQueryFailed));
    var d = $.Deferred();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    var result = currentUser.get_title();
       d.resolve(result);
   },
   function(sender,args){
       d.reject(args);
   });
   return d.promise();
} 


function checkCounterVal(callback) {

var retVarNm = 0;      

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://Your_Site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('HitCounter')/Items?$select=Counter&$top=1&$orderby=Created desc",
        method: "GET",
        cache: false,
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {  

            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) { 

            if(data.d.results[i].Counter != null) {                       
                        retVarNm = data.d.results[i].Counter; 
                $("#pageVisitCount").text("Page Hit: " + retVarNm);
            }           

                      } 

            callback(retVarNm);  

        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Failed to check counter");           
        }
         });//ajax closed

}
```